# When Cantor's Intersection theorem won't work with closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Give an example to show that Cantor's Intersection Theorem would not be true if compact sets were replaced by closed sets.

---

Compact set is closed and bounded, so what I'm going to find is something that is closed but not bounded.

By the Cantor theorem, which says that a decreasing sequence of non-empty compact subset will have a non-empty intersection.

What I was trying to approach is how two sets just "touched" and as if they have not bounded, two sets "touched" nothing. But I cant give an example for that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the intersection of all sets of the form $[n,\infty)$, where $n$ ranges over the positive integers.

Comment: I had intended $n$ to range over the positive integers, and have modified the post to make that clear. Over all reals is fine too, but I wanted the intersection to be a countable intersection, since that gives a stronger result.

Comment: but (my concept isn't very good), isnt the set $[0,\infty)$ will cover all the other sets? or say intersect with every $n>0$?

Comment: It is an **intersection**, not a union. Let $U_n=[n,\infty)$. Then we are looking at the nested sequence $U_1,U_2,U_3,\dots$.